# Why does my vim lags when scrolling?

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu-12.04

I am facing a strange issue with my vim setup. My vim starts to lag when I scroll a file using arrow keys and by lag I mean the scrolling is very slow and is not at all smooth.

**Vim in tilda/guake/gnome-terminal**

When using the above terminal emulators vim lags and my CPU usage rose to around 30-35%. I also tried `vim -u None file.txt` and `vim --noplugin file.txt` but no significant change was observed although my cpu-usage was around 30% and scrolling was better than previous but it was still slow and lagging. `file.txt` is around 200 lines.

**xterm/eterm/aterm**

I get perfect scrolling without any lags.And by perfect I mean smooth scrolling without any delay and that too without any flags like `--noplugin etc`. My cpu-usage is around 10-15%.

I also tried `gvim` and in this case the scrolling was somewhere in between `tilda and xterm`. Although not perfect.

So, what can be the reason behind the lags I get in vim while scrolling because I don't want to stop using my drop-down terminal.

My config:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- 2GB RAM
- Intel GMA 3600 chipset(infamous because no proper linux driver)
- [My .vimrc](http://pastie.org/4597632)

Comment: I think your question will be more suitable on superuser.com

Comment: Before logging in, press alt+ctrl+f1 to go to console #1. Login and try vim. Do you see the same problem again ?

Comment: @ArashThr: It works fine(smooth scrolling) when I login to console #1 and use vim.

Comment: Bro, did you get the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you've already answered part of the question - it's most likely not `vim` that's causing the additional CPU load, since `vim` doesn't really behave significantly differently for different terminal emulators (at least usually - I'm sure it can be customized to do different things based on terminal, but that's fairly uncommon, I would think). For the terminals that show higher CPU usage, do you have image backgrounds (especially backgrounds that scroll with the text pane), transparency, or other GUI effects/eye candy enabled on them that might contribute? Do you have GL/GLX working correctly on the system so such things are offloaded to the GPU rather than being done by your main CPU?

Comment: I am using tilda and I don't have any eye-candy effects enabled on it. I am able to play H264 encoded videos in my netbook and my cpu-usage is arnd 10-15% so I guess my GPU is doing fine. Although  there is no proper 2D/3D support for gma3600 till now.